# Next JS project does not create optimized production build

Tags: next.js

I have inherited a Next JS app and am new to the process. I am trying to run the program locally and cannot get the program to compile. When I execute `npm run build`, I see the following

[image]

I have run `npm install` and am using `npm v 9.5.0` and `node v 16.13.0`. Could I be missing some package or need to install something?